# Bind variable to Mat-select value with form control

Tags: angular, typescript

In my typescript code I have a variable called `type`, its value is input by its parent component. The `type` value is a string that can be empty upon receiving it from the parent component. Also in this file I have code that will be used for form validation.

```
@Input() public type = '';


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

public ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
    // do stuff
  });
}


public myForm = this.fb.group({
  myType: [this.type, Validators.required],
});
```

In my HTML, I have a form group called `myForm` that contains a mat-select dropdown. The mat-select's value is bound to the `type` variable, this way if `type` has a valid value that was passed from the parent, it will display by default in the dropdown. If `type` has an empty string value, users will have to select something from the dropdown. There is also a formControlName attribute on the mat-select so it can be validated by the TS code.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(value)]="type" formControlName="myType">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types; let i=index" [value]="t">
          {{t}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
 
  <button mat-button type="submit"
    [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My issue is, when I include the `formControlName` attribute, it seems like the mat-select no longer binds the value of `type` to its selected value. So if `type` has a value passed from its parent, that will not be shown as the default value within the dropdown and users will be forced to select something from the dropdown. I do want to keep the `formControlName` tag to use it for validation when hitting the submit button.

Is there something I can do so that if `type` has a valid value it will show by default in the mat-select as the selected value. But if `type` is an empty string, users will have to select something from the dropdown. And then the form control validates that something was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Delete de ngModel way from your form in HTML (the *'**Banana in a box** [()]'* ):

```
<mat-select formControlName="myType">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types; let i=index" [value]="t">
          {{t}}
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

2. Then, change the way you get 'type' variable from parent, with a **getter**:

```
@Input() 
get type(myType: string) {
   if ( myType && this.myForm) {
      this.myForm.patchValue({myType});
   };
}
```

Just in case you don't get value when the form is declaration/building, change this:

```
public myForm = this.fb.group({
  myType: [this.type ?? '', Validators.required],
});

// NOTE: if ?? doesn't work in you angular version, change it by this:
// myType: [this.type ? this.type : '', Validators.required],
```

Comment: For the getter, What's 'vaulePArent'

Comment: Sorry, I will edit, it was the value send by parent component, which is in 'myType'.